# Facebook API - See Posts which have tagged my Facebook page

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I want to use the Facebook API to retrieve all posts/status updates on all users which have tagged my Facebook page. I have searched a lot and did not find any solution.

Any solution that you know of guys?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Facebook does not expose an API that supports this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this API.

When you use /{page-id}/tagged to show the posts that tag this page, the results include posts from other pages only if those pages are verified.

Link : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/feed/